# Dynamically selecting columns in pandas based on a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe like this:

```
    Month    Day Birthday
0   Jan      31  Yes
1   Apr      30  No
2   Mar      31  Yes
3   June     30  Yes
```

How would I select the columns dynamically and append them to another list? For example:

```
d= [Birthday, Month, Day, ...]
xx=[]
for f in range(len(d)):
    loan = df[f].values.tolist()
    xx.append(loan)
```

So that `xx` is the following:

```
[Yes,No,Yes,Yes,Jan,Apr,Mar,June,...]
```

Something like this but on a much larger scale.

I keep getting the following error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

When I try

```
for f in range(len(d)):
    loan = df[d[f]].values.tolist()
```

I get

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xx = df.T.to_numpy().flatten().tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> xx
['Jan', 'Apr', 'Mar', 'June', 31, 30, 31, 30, 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes']
```

Or,

```
xx = df.to_numpy().flatten().tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> xx
['Jan', 31, 'Yes', 'Apr', 30, 'No', 'Mar', 31, 'Yes', 'June', 30, 'Yes']
```

Comment: Hi, i can easily make it all into a multiple dimensional area but i want it into a 1x1 list based on my set inputs or a set of inputs from a list that's the problem atm but thank  you

Comment: Oh I see, so like `['Jan', 31, 'Yes', 'Apr', 30, 'No' ...]` or `['Jan', 'Apr', ..., 31, 20, ..., 'Yes', 'No', ...]`? Which one?

Comment: maybe do a `ravel` or `flatten` before tolist?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
out = df[d].T.values.flatten().tolist()
```

With `df[d]`, you can change the position of the columns according to `d`, the transpose the dataframe using `T`, select values as array, `flatten` the array and convert to list.

Output:

```
['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Jan', 'Apr', 'Mar', 'June', 31, 30, 31, 30]
```